# Shaded graph/network plot?

Tags: r, graph, plot, sna

I am trying to plot quite large and dense networks ([dput here](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/151931eca021b1230d22)). All I end up with is a bunch of overlapping dots, which does not really give me a sense of the structure or density of the network:

```
library(sna)
plot(data, mode = "fruchtermanreingold")
```

[image]

However, I have seen plots which utilizes fading to visualize the degree to which points overlap, e.g.:

[image]

How can I implement this "fading" in a plot of a graph?

Comment: If you want illustrations of how coloring code works in R you should post a _small_ example. First line(s) should be `library(....)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I have posted exactly what I'm doing included the data in a `dput`. Are you wondering which SNA library I'm using?

Comment: That was not a small example and I still do not know what package is being used. I suppose I could ferret it out by scrolling to the end to figure out what class name is at the end of the object but why should I need to?

Comment: Perhaps all you are asking for is whether to use [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) (i.e., partial transparency). In that case, try using something like `plot(..., col='#ff000080')`; the color string is `#RRGGBBAA` where each pair is a hexademical value for red, green, blue, and alpha, and an alpha of 0x80 is 128/255 =~ 50% transparency. (Since you haven't provided any reproducibility -- and `sna` does not appear to directly reference "fruchtermanreingold" -- I'm unable to help any more than this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(sna)
library(network)

source("modifieddatafromgist.R")

plot.network(data, 
             vertex.col="#FF000020", 
             vertex.border="#FF000020", 
             edge.col="#FFFFFF")
```

[image]

First, I added a `data <-` to the gist so it could be sourced.

Second, you need to ensure the proper `library` calls so the object classes are assigned correctly and the proper `plot` function will be used.

Third, you should use the extra parameters for the `fruchtermanreingold` layout (which is the default one for `plot.network`) to expand the area and increase the # of iterations.

Fourth, you should do a `set.seed` before the plot so folks can reproduce the output example.

Fifth, I deliberately removed cruft so you can see the point overlap, but you can change the alpha for both edges & vertices (and you should change the edge width, too) to get the result you want.

There's a ton of help in `?plot.network` to assist you in configuring these options.